# Bar Plot Value over bar candle

Tags: matplotlib

My bar plot graph having big count value and displays top of bar horizontal, These values are overlapping and taking big area due to huge count value ..[i want like this ,counts are displaying vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEyCK.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide us with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your coding attempts so we can guide you towards an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':pd.date_range('2020-09-10', periods=10), 'trades':np.random.randint(40000,99999, 10)})

ax = df.plot.bar(x='dates', y='trades')
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()/2),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='w', xytext=(0, 5),
                 textcoords='offset points', rotation=90)
ax.set_xticklabels(df['dates'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'));
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @ Scott Boston , it worked perfectly for me..